# ggplot: How to avoid overwriting of parameter value in function call using ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
densityplot_function = function(dsname , varno  )
{
aa =   names(dsname[varno]);
print(aa); 
ggplot(dsname, aes(x=aa , fill=category_var)) + geom_density(alpha=0.09);
print(graph);
}
densityplot_function(dsname , 3);
densityplot_function(dsname , 65);
densityplot_function(dsname , 68);
```

the plot comes only for variable 3 but not for 65 and 68
the same plot for variable 3 gets repeated?

Comment: You use `print(graph)` but it seems you don't define `graph`..? Did you create it in advance? (fyi, you don't need semicolons at the end of each line, only if you wanted to write several commands on the same line)

Comment: @Cgvenkatesh In addition you have `aes(x=aa..`, which I guess is not a variable in your dataset `dsname`?  Please consider to provide a small reproducible example of `dsname`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess as you provide no data and some of your code does not make sense.

```
densityplot_function = function(dsname , varno, category_var) {
  require(ggplot2)
  aa <- names(dsname[varno])
  print(aa)
  graph <- ggplot(dsname,aes_string(x=aa,group=category_var,fill=category_var)) + 
    geom_density(alpha=0.09)
  print(graph)
}
densityplot_function(iris , 1, "Species")
densityplot_function(iris , 2, "Species")
densityplot_function(iris , 4, "Species")
```

Note the use of `aes_string(...)` instead of `aes(...)` and the use of `group=category`.

Here is the output of the first call:

[image]